# Server-side virtual DOM, what session state overhead in Blazor?

Tags: blazor-server-side, session-state, overhead

Before committing to a Blazor Server project I need to understand what additional server session-state storage is imposed by the Razor-Components architecture. I understand that a Virtual DOM is an essential element of how Blazor works and a virtual dom is probably a sound concept e.g. it is a foundational element of ReactJS.

What concerns me is that when all of Blazor runs server-side then the virtual dom must be hosted server-side as well in order for the Blazor framework to dispatch html delta commands to the client browser.

I would be interested to hear any estimates of the likely size of the virtual dom per client connection for a non trivial SPA application.

As a point of comparison, when designing a regular .NET Webapi application I try to keep user session state well below 1k in size.